# connected host has failed to respond 10.114.23.200:80

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting below error message and I am connecting to Microsoft graph api to read emails.
I hae given appid and requeored permission.

I am using the code from github https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp

please help me

THanks,
Rajendra
[image]

Comment: It's not a configuration issue of the sample code. I follow  It should be caused by the network environment. Please have a check with the firewall and any other possible network factor.

Comment: Hi, are there any updates?